# vertical line and extension of node in tree

Tags: tikz-trees, plot

I'm trying to generate a tree that has a vertical line coming through exactly in the middle, right after the 0.5 on the top node, and the 2 on the bottome node, and I would like to write 1.25,1.25 directly after it, in a sense extending the node

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=2em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = []
\begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
  \node (a) at ( 0,0) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
  \node (b) at ( 4,-1.5) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{0.5},\textcolor{purple}{2}$};
  \node (c) at ( 4,1.5) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{2},\textcolor{purple}{0.5}$};
  \node (e) at ( 8,0) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
  \draw [->] (a) to node [below] {$1/2$} (b);
  \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$1/2$} (c);
  \draw [->] (c) to node [above] {$1/2$} (e);
  \draw [->] (b) to node [below] {$1/2$} (e);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is there a straight forward way to do this? An image of what I'm trying to get:
[image]

although i would prefer a more subtle, dashed straight line, i'd also like to write some text below or it if possible

Comment: Can you add an image of the desired result? Your description is confusing to me. By the way, your graph is not a tree.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina updated

Comment: @dimebucker91, your code is not even close to your picture, it seems to be from some other picture. Can you update it with this what you doing so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility showing three options:

- The first two ones, using your TikZ approach and using first a straight line and then using a `snake` decoration:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

  \tikzset{
    bag/.style={text width=2em, text centered},
   end/.style={}
  } 

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
    \node (a) at ( 0,0) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
    \node (b) at ( 4,-1.5) [bag,text width=4em] {$\textcolor{blue}{0.5},\textcolor{purple}{2\phantom{.5}}$};
    \node (c) at ( 4,1.5) [bag,text width=3em] {$\textcolor{blue}{\phantom{.5}2},\textcolor{purple}{0.5}$};
    \node (e) at ( 8,0) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
    \draw [->] (a) to node[below] {$1/2$} (b);
    \draw [->] (a) to node[above] {$1/2$} (c);
    \draw [->] (c.south east) to node[above] {$1/2$} (e);
    \draw [->] (b) to node[below] {$1/2$} (e);
    \draw ([yshift=2ex]c.north) -- ([yshift=-2ex]b.south) node[below] {$\textcolor{blue}{1.25},\textcolor{purple}{1.25}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip


  \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped,decoration=snake]
    \node (a) at ( 0,0) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
    \node (b) at ( 4,-1.5) [bag,text width=4em] {$\textcolor{blue}{0.5},\textcolor{purple}{2\phantom{.5}}$};
    \node (c) at ( 4,1.5) [bag,text width=3em] {$\textcolor{blue}{\phantom{.5}2},\textcolor{purple}{0.5}$};
    \node (e) at ( 8,0) [bag] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
    \draw [->] (a) to node[below] {$1/2$} (b);
    \draw [->] (a) to node[above] {$1/2$} (c);
    \draw [->] (c.south east) to node[above] {$1/2$} (e);
    \draw [->] (b) to node[below] {$1/2$} (e);
    \draw[decorate] ([yshift=2ex]c.north) -- ([yshift=-2ex]b.south) node[below] {$\textcolor{blue}{1.25},\textcolor{purple}{1.25}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

  You might want to add some additional space between the numbers in the last example.
- And an option using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep=2cm,
  execute at end picture={
    \draw ([yshift=2ex]top.north) -- ([yshift=-2ex]bottom.south)
      node[below] {$\textcolor{blue}{1.25},\textcolor{purple}{1.25}$};
    }
  ]
  & |[alias=top]|\textcolor{blue}{\phantom{.5}2},\textcolor{purple}{0.5}\ar[dr,"1/2"] & \\
   \textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}\ar[ur,"1/2"]\ar[dr,"1/2",swap] & & \textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1} \\
  & |[alias=bottom]|\textcolor{blue}{0.5},\textcolor{purple}{2\phantom{.5}}\ar[ur,"1/2",swap] &
  \end{tikzcd}

  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code remind me on sketch of automate, so the following code maybe is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,quotes,positioning}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 24mm and 42mm,
                 > = {Stealth[length=5pt,width=4pt]},
bar/.style = {inner ysep=2pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {sloped, anchor=north}
                        ]
\node (a) [bar]             {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
\node (b) 
     [bar,below right=of a] {$\textcolor{blue}{0.5},\textcolor{purple}{2}$};
\node (c) 
     [bar,above right=of b] {$\textcolor{blue}{1},\textcolor{purple}{1}$};
\node (d) 
     [bar,above right=of a] {$\textcolor{blue}{2},\textcolor{purple}{0.5}$};
\path[->]   (a) edge ["$1/2$"]  (b)
            (b) edge ["$1/2$"]  (c)
            (a) edge ["$1/2$"]  (d)
            (d) edge ["$1/2$"]  (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Picture:

[image: on]

**Upgrade:** Well, another answer is already accepted and by this is more clear, what is the question. Anyway, another (I think simple) solution is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz, ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,quotes,positioning}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style = {sloped, anchor=north},
       every node/.style = {font=\bfseries,text width=1.5em, align=center}
                        ]
\node (a)                    {\textcolor{blue}{1},\;\textcolor{purple}{1}};
\node (b1) [left]   at (4,2) {\textcolor{blue}{0.5}};
\node (b2) [right]  at (4,2) {\textcolor{purple}{2}};
\node (c)           at (8,0) {\textcolor{blue}{2},\;\textcolor{purple}{0.5}};
\node (d1) [left]   at (4,-2){\textcolor{blue}{1}};
\node (d2) [right]  at (4,-2){\textcolor{purple}{1}};
\path[very thick,purple,->]
    (a) edge["$1/2$"] (b1.west)
    (a) edge["$1/2$"] (d1.west)
    (b2.east) edge["$1/2$"] (c)
    (d2.east) edge["$1/2$"] (c);
\draw[decorate,decoration=snake,thick] (b1.north east) -- (d1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]